# chrome not reachable Selenium webDriverException

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Option values when creating drivers

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_deriver_manager = ChromeDriverManager()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_deriver_manager.install(), options=options)
```

On the remote server(ubuntu on EC2) via ssh, Attempt to run Python scripts using selenium via `nohup python3 ~~. py> ~/log.out &`
It works well when maintaining the ssh connection with the server. But an error occurs a few seconds after disconnecting the ssh

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
> (Session info: headless chrome=102.0.5005.61)

How do I complete the script even after I close the ssh connection?

I've already tried to terminate Chrome and Web Driver processes before executing the script

brower and web driver version info

```
> google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 102.0.5005.61

> chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 102.0.5005.61 (0e59bcc00cc4985ce39ad31c150065f159d95ad3-refs/branch-heads/5005@{#819})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `screen`, hitting enter and then entering the nohup-command

Answer (score 1):

Could you share a bit more of your code?
I was having the same issue. It turns out I wasn't waiting long enough for javascript to generate what I was trying to access. Adding

```
time.sleep(5)
```

or using

```
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'myclass')))
```

solved the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, but this doesn’t solve it for me. I already used webdriverwait.